# Object creation and declaration in c#

Tags: c#, object, instance, declaration

The following code creates an object firstApple.  it is just valid inside the goTesco method. When threat goes out the method, firstApple  "changes" to null.

I would like to retake that object in other Clases within same domain. What is the best practice. Thanks

```
public Class Market {

   private static Apple firstApple;

   private static void goTesco ()
   {
      firstApple = new Apple();
   }
}
```

Comment: "When threat goes out the method, firstApple "changes" to null."... no, it does not. If it does, then there is other code you did not show that does it.

Comment: return firstApple; no need for the static field.

Comment: The method assigns a non-null expression to the field `firstApple`, and then the field will have that value, also after control has left the method, as long as the program runs. Until someone else assigns to `firstApple`. The two members of your class are `private`, so they cannot be used (easily) from other classes, like you say you want. Consider changing the members to from `private` to `internal`, for example.

Comment: oK right. it changes to null when the threat goes back to Main method.

I create an instance class. how do I get firstApple from the main program, is it just possible as citykid says? "return firstApple"

Comment: or public static Apple firstApple { get; set; } ??

Comment: Which is the best approach?

Comment: Use public Apple firstApple { get; set; } as a property and you can instantiate in your Main. It is private now you cannot access it from outside. Or you can change your method is public.

Comment: @AnılCanlı tmm Tesekk! Understood!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the best practice is not to use static fields.

From you comments it looks like it should be result of the call or maybe value set somewhere on end of custom thread. Without seeing code it is hard to say what you need, but consider `async` methods or using `Tasks`  directly to implement asynchronous processing and easily obtaining results.